# Закрытие ссылки после нажатия

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<a href="http://www.website.com" target="_blank" >LinkText</a>
```

как сделать так чтобы открывшаяся ссылка сразу закрылась?

Comment: жмешь на ссылку, она открывается в новой вкладке и надо чтобы сразу закрылась сама

Answer (score 3):

Сам нашел.

```
<a href="#" id="target">Click to open popup</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {

  document.getElementById("target").onclick = function() {
    var wnd = window.open("http://stackoverflow.com");
    setTimeout(function() {
      wnd.close();
    }, 5000);
    return false;
  };

})();
```

Comment: Молодец. *(7 символов нужно...)*